# How to Calculate String Length in Pixels in uwp in C#?

Tags: c#, uwp

How to Calculate String Length in Pixels in uwp in C#?

I found some answers to my question for previous versions, but not for UWP (Windows 10).

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

If you use xaml, you can create the textblock with your string, then call 'Measure' method. Following SO post may helps you.

[How can I measure the Text Size in UWP Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969056/)

or if you using win2d,

[How to calculate the size of a piece of text in Win2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696838/)

Comment: The first link answered my question. Thank you.

Comment: Please remember to mark the replies as answers if it helps you. Thanks! =)