# Using Win2D is it possible to get text size without a drawingSession?

Tags: win2d

This question is different from this question - [How to calculate the size of a piece of text in Win2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696838/how-to-calculate-the-size-of-a-piece-of-text-in-win2d/30937214#comment113331881_30937214) - because that method has the result attached to the draw event of a Win2D CanvasControl. Specifically, it requires the DrawingSession of the arguments.

I want to know if it is possible to know the size of the text without having the draw function called. This is desired because I need the various CanvasControls I am using widths or heights to be able to be set by the size of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of the [CanvasTextLayout](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Text_CanvasTextLayout.htm) class with the text and format and get the DrawBounds property of it.

```
using (var layout = new CanvasTextLayout(creator, "Hello world", format, 200, 100))
{
   var bounds = layout.DrawBounds;
}
```